# google maps js v3 xml is null

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, xml, google-maps-api-3

Im trying to retrieve the XML and put it into the var markers, when I run it the line

```
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
```

I get an error saying XML is null, here is the XML I get when running the file that produces the XML

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
  <markers>
 <marker name="funtimes" address="5451 Forest Cove Lane" lat="34.1519" lng="-118.774717" type="Basketball" desc="going to play fun times with fun people" date="2012-12-29" time="23:00:00" eventcap="4" eventcur="10" eventid="1" admin="true"/>
 <marker name="Event test" address="1231 fake st" lat="34.1517" lng="-118.77234" type="Cycling" desc="just a description" date="2013-01-31" time="12:00:00" eventcap="10" eventcur="4" eventid="2" admin="true"/>
 <marker name="Event test 2" address="1231 fake st" lat="34.1512" lng="-118.77421" type="Football" desc="just a description 2" date="2013-01-31" time="12:00:00" eventcap="10" eventcur="3" eventid="3" admin="true"/>
 <marker name="funtimes" address="5451 Forest Cove Lane" lat="34.1519" lng="-118.774717" type="Basketball" desc="going to play fun times with fun people" date="2012-12-29" time="23:00:00" eventcap="4" eventcur="10" eventid="1" admin="false"/>    
 <marker name="Event test" address="1231 fake st" lat="34.1517" lng="-118.77234" type="Cycling" desc="just a description" date="2013-01-31" time="12:00:00" eventcap="10" eventcur="4" eventid="2" admin="false"/>
 <marker name="Event test 2" address="1231 fake st" lat="34.1512" lng="-118.77421" type="Football" desc="just a description 2" date="2013-01-31" time="12:00:00" eventcap="10" eventcur="3" eventid="3" admin="false"/>
 <marker name="Event test 3" address="2142 fake st" lat="34.1602" lng="-118.77789" type="Football" desc="just a description 3" date="2013-01-28" time="13:00:00" eventcap="8" eventcur="2" eventid="4" admin="false"/>
 </markers>
```

Here is some of the surrounding code

```
downloadUrl("mapXML2.php", function(data) {
var xml = data.responseXML;
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

 function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map won't display points - XML is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848052/google-map-wont-display-points-xml-is-null), look at both answers.

Comment: his problem was a lacking,

    header("Content-type: text/xml");

I have that in my file that makes the xml

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175708/xml-to-javascript-array-google-maps/14176221#14176221

Comment: Can you open the xml in a browser?  What browser are you getting this error in?

Comment: I can open the xml in firefox I posted what the results are in the initial question. also the error is in firefox

Answer (score 1):

I have run your code from [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586996/google-maps-not-loading-showing-just-a) with my generated XML with no errors. If the line `header("Content-type: text/xml")` is removed in my file I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null` This shows you are not sending the header. Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

Try

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);
//Connect to database
```